# How to modify svm.cpp to calculate distance between point and hyperplane ? (LIBSVM)

Tags: c++, libsvm

I want to calculate the distance between point and hyperplane using LIBSVM (not in MATLAB). I tried to follow these instructions, but I think I failed. http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvm/faq.html#f4151

Did someone successfully changed the svm.cpp to calculate distance between point and hyperplane ? And if you did can you explain me how ?

I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: Do you have some code you've already tried?

Comment: I don't know C++ yet, so i don't wrote a lot of code. I will try to find it and then post.

Answer (score 0):

From the libsvm code found on [GitHub](https://github.com/cjlin1/libsvm/blob/master/svm.cpp#L747), you have:

```
{
    double v = 0;
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<l;i++)
        v += alpha[i] * (G[i] + p[i]);

    si->obj = v/2;
}
```

The instructions on your [website](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvm/faq.html#f4151) say:

1. In that place, si->obj is the variable for the objective value
2. Add a for loop to calculate the sum of alpha
3. Calculate 2*(si->obj + sum of alpha) and print the square root of it. You now get |w|. You need to recompile the code

So the new code would be:

```
{
    double v = 0;
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<l;i++)
        v += alpha[i] * (G[i] + p[i]);
    si->obj = v/2;

    double sum_alpha = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i<l; ++i) {
        sum_alpha += alpha[i];
    }
    double w_square = 2*(si->obj + sum_alpha);
    double w = sqrt(w_square);

    printf("The value for abs(w) is %f \n", w);
}
```

Comment: Mind you:  I didn't investigate what the si->obj = v/2; computation was about.  You might need to move the extra loop to calculate w before you modify obj.

Comment: I tryed ur code but he don't print in any out file ( i used grep to check) "The value for abs(w) is" if someone know where it's suppose to be printed. I would like to know.

Comment: Printf prints to stdout.  So probably your console window.